# What does the `p-N` and its variants represent in Bootstrap v4?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I find the naming in Bootstrap v4 less than intuitive.

I know they want to minimise the impact all the classes cluttering up the markup, but I just can't come to a reasonable conclusion. I can guess - but I can't find concrete answers.

- **p-1, p-2, p-N**: Flexbox related, but what does the `p` stand for?
- **d-flex**: Flexbox related, but what does the `d` stand for? Perhaps `display`?
- **mr-auto** - Elliots cousin? Guessing margin related - perhaps `margin-right-auto` but can't confirm in the docs.
- **mt-auto** - ?
- **ml-auto** - ?

Comment: "Elliot's cousin" ,lol

Answer (score 55, accepted):

They are the new [spacing utility](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) classes. I think they're very intuitive:

- `p-*` is for padding all sides.
- `m-*` is for margin all sides.
- `pl-*` is for padding left.
- `mt-*` is for margin top.
- `mr-auto` is for margin right auto.

[Spacing Utils Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/kaWaobOUD8)

There are also [display utilties](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/display-property/).

`d-block`, `d-flex`, `d-inline-block`, `d-none` etc...

Comment: Thanks ZimSystem - I guess I am looking for a bit of the `p`, `d`, `ml`, etc actually stand for. I will update my question to clarify

Comment: Just saw your update - perfect - I didn't notice that part of the docs!

Comment: What is the difference between these two below, any idea?                    <div class="d-flex flex-row">                                                                 <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start end">