# What's the meaning of ml in bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

Hi I'm using bootstrap4 beta.
I noticed that it uses the classes; ml-auto or mr-auto, instead of pull-right and pull-left.
I can guess l is left and r is right.
What's the meaning of m beside l and r?
Is it margin?

Comment: Sometimes it's quite useful to read [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the \`p-N\` and its variants represent in Bootstrap v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42160532/what-does-the-p-n-and-its-variants-represent-in-bootstrap-v4)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's short for: margin-left

So `ml-auto` means `margin-left: auto` which aligns an element to the right.